# When to combine and minify vs fetch via cdn

Tags: javascript, css, zurb-foundation, concatenation, minify

I've been digging into a number of recent templates (mainly Foundation 5, but some others) and noticing a trend.  Quite a few people seem to be combining js and css files, but not ALL of them.

For instance, looking at a template right now where everything is dumped into styles.css file EXCEPT that normalize.css is being called via cdn separately.

I see the same for the js.  Most are combined into single file then minimized, but not all.

Is there a general reason for this?  Does it have to do with certain common resources persisting in the browser?  For instance, if I guess that users have normalize.css already in browser from hitting another site, and from that particular cdn, does it then make my page load faster to have it as a separate call since their computer then ignores that call and uses copy already loaded?

Or, is there another reason?

In either case, is there some sort of rule of thumb to dictate when to or not to combine into a single minified css and js file?

Comment: The browser will cache the CDN resource and use it across different sites for the same user, so that part of your thinking is correct.

Comment: Ok, so I understand it may be debatable and involves guessing as to your end user's habits, but since I don't have enough of a frame of reference, is it generally considered best practice to then keep certain files OUT of the combined file?  If so, which?  Normalize? Jquery? Modernizr?  Is this still true if your Modernizr is lighter custom build?  Just trying to put it in perspective to get rule of thumb.

Comment: It also depends on whether the site in question uses the closure compiler with advanced optimizations, doing so is *much* easier if you concatenate

Comment: I don't think there's a best practice since there are many situations, but common sense can help. Two scenarios are packing third-party files in with your own, or linking to CDNs for third-party files and having just your files packed up. The first scenario does mean that on the first visit, a user must download the CDN resources with your packed files. The second scenario means the user, likely with cached CDN resources, wouldn't have to download those third-party files on the first visit. After the first visit, the load speeds are going to be identical since everything will be cached.

Comment: What you need to do is find what works for you and your userbase. If your users are likely on the Internet an average amount or more, then you can probably safely assume they have cached CDN resources.  If they're barely on the Internet, they might not have cached CDN resources. But also ask if you need that tiny performance boost, and you'll probably want to analyze your user base's general connection speeds.

Comment: Ok.  Is it significantly slower for those who don't have cached resource yet?  I am using Webhook which serves static sites with a combining and minification grunt script, though I am not clear just exactly what closure compiler or advanced optimizations means exactly, so I will look up those terms.

Comment: The speed difference of loading a CDN resource vs. getting it from cache is going to be minimal on anyone with broadband or better.  There might be a few seconds delay on DSL.  That is all highly dependent on country/region/infrastructure of the user in question.  [Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/) is an advanced Google tool for minifying and optimizing JS code, that a lot of frameworks include in their toolchain.  "Advanced optimizations" sounds like a custom set of optimizations that Webhook provides, so you'll have to look at their docs.